# Ruby: How to copy the multidimensional array in new array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

seating_arrangement 
      `[
         [:first, :second, :none],
         [:first, :none, :second],
         [:second, :second, :first],
        ]`

I need to copy this array into new array. I tried to do it by following code:

```
class Simulator
 @@current_state

def initialize(seating_arrangement)
  @@current_state = seating_arrangement.dup
end
```

But whenever I am making any changes to `seating_arrangement` `current_state` changes automatically. I wanted to keep `current_state` separately. I am newbie in `ruby`. Please help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dup` does not create a deep copy, it copies only the outermost object. From that docs:

> Produces a shallow copy of obj—the instance variables of obj are copied, but not the objects they reference. dup copies the tainted state of obj.

If you are not sure how deep your object might be nested then the easiest way to create deep copy might be to serialize and de-serialize the object:

```
@@current_state = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(seating_arrangement))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def initialize(seating_arrangement)
  @@current_state = seating_arrangement.map(&:dup)
end
```

Comment: And use an instance variable `@current_state` instead of a class variable `@@current_state`.

Comment: @sawa is the best ^.^

Comment: @sawa 
Thanks for the replying but I am getting an exception in following code:
`prev_state = @@current_state.map (&:dup)`  i.e. unexpected & (SyntaxError)

prev_state is another local variable in a method

Comment: Careful... This solution is limited to a two dimensional array which holds only objects that respond to `#dup`... i.e. mixing Symbols into the array would raise an exception and having a third dimension, or even a string inside the second dimension would create a shallow copy (`[ ["this won't be copied"], :raises_an_exception]`).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Rails 4.x or above, just use:

```
 array.deep_dup
```

[See doc.](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/Array/deep_dup)